# bullet points inserted in floating image but should be next to it

Tags: html, css

I have a floating image in a paragraph and also some list items.
The bullet points of the list items are "in" the image.

Image showcasing my problem:
[image]

What is the best way to let them start at the appropriate place (right after the image?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style> 
  img {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <img src="photo.jpeg" style="float: left;"/>
    <p>
    <ul>
      <li>This photo is amazing</li>
      <li>Great view!</li>
      <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
      <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Close your `<p>` tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `list-style-position: inside`

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" style="float: left;" />
<p> Some text</p>
<ul>
  <li>This photo is amazing</li>
  <li>Great view!</li>
  <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
  <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why does the UL overlap the IMG?  checkout the LI width in development tools

Comment: @DCR because the image is floating, and it float only around the text so it will be above the ul/li and will push only the text not the entire li

Comment: @DCR it's also the same for `p` check this : https://jsfiddle.net/2Ld3rxeh/ .. it's how float works

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two block elements side by side to really have them float properly together. Here are a couple of options for you, one using floats and one using flexbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style> 
  img {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Float</h1>
  <div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <img src="timber_logo.jpg" style="float:left;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <ul>
        <li>This photo is amazing</li>
        <li>Great view!</li>
        <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
        <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Need to clear the floats -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>

<h1>Flex</h1>
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div>
        <img src="timber_logo.jpg" style="float:left;"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li>This photo is amazing</li>
        <li>Great view!</li>
        <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
        <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This photo is amazing

Great view!

But why are the bullet points in the photo??

Good question, indeed!

Add style to the ul class. [padding-left: 400px;]

Answer (score -1):

This photo is amazing

Great view!

But why are the bullet points in the photo??

Good question, indeed!

Add style to the ul class. [padding-left: 400px;]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style> 
  img {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <img src="photo.jpeg" style="float: left;"/>
    <p>
    <ul style="padding-left: 400px;">
      <li>This photo is amazing</li>
      <li>Great view!</li>
      <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
      <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This will work but if you add a background color then you will see that the elements overlap which may not be ideal.